# try-catch exception in c++

Tags: c++, exception, polymorphism, try-catch

I was asked to use try-catch exception handling to handle the case if the list of students is empty. I'm new to exception handling can someone guide me? Below is the implementation of average method. I need to use try-catch to make sure the list isn't empty.

```
double classAverage()
{
  int count = 0;
  double sum = 0.0;
  Container *temp = list;


if (temp == NULL)
{

    cout << "List empty!";
    return -1.0;
}

    while (temp != NULL)
    {

        sum += temp->student->getGrade();
        temp = temp->next;
        count++;
    }
    return sum / count;
```

}

Comment: It's not a great choice to back out into a "bad" design because you can't get something working. Make the "correct" way work. IOW, don't make the student grade *public* and exposed; get the function working correctly.

Comment: Do you pass a valid `Student*` to `changeGrade`?

Comment: They point a copy of that pointer elsewhere, they don't modify the original. I'm trying to work out what doesn't work, as the OP isn't explicit

Comment: You will need to add values to `sum`, since that is the definition of `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `changeGrade` is a friend of `Student`, this should work:

```
void changeGrade(Student* s, int newGrade) {
    s->grade = newGrade;
}
```

Right now you repoint the pointer `s` to a new `Student` object. What you want
is to change the object that was passed in to the function.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information, but I think your code might look like this:

```
Student* student = new Student("John", "Doe", 99, 1);
changeGrade(student, 9);
```

This won't change the student at all, because you pass the pointer by value, so when you reassign it, the original object (the pointer `student`) is not changed. For the calling code to notice a change you have to pass by ***reference*** (`Student*&` - recommended way) or using a pointer to a pointer (`Student**);`. Also, don't forget to delete the original pointer (`Student*`) if you are using the `Student**` approach, or you'll leak memory.

---

You shouldn't make a way around not setting the `int`, its probably bad practice and confusing.